# Enhancement of the open source lib for calculation of IRR (internal rate rate)

Tags: loans, calculation, principal

I am cs student , and has been asked to enhance the documentation for open source lib `finance.js` for `IIR` (internal rate of return) for various industry

Here I am trying to calculate IIR for the below bank scenario, to easily make use of the open source lib.

[image of the bank scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxhCT.png)

Here in the above scenario , `principal amount` is `50000000` , `upfront Fee` is `1000000` and `upfront credit line Fee` is `0`

I am aware the IIR is calculated using the formula mentioned in the [invetopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp).

I am unable to understand what will be `Net cash inflow during the period t` and what will be the `t`?
Does the `total inital investment cost` will be `principal amount - upfront Fee`

​
​